# How can I add a style property to the actual class itself?

Tags: jquery

I have this function that sets the padding on an element to be the height of the header. It works fine, but what I am trying to achieve is for the style to be applied to the .main selector, as opposed to the element.style. Is this possible in jQuery?

```js
$(function() {
  $(window)
    .bind('resize', function() {
      var headerHeight = $('header').height();

      $('#main').css('padding-top', headerHeight);
    })
    .trigger('resize');
});
```

```css
.main {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header id='header'>
  <h1>Header</h1>
</header>

<main id='main' class='main'>
  <p>Some text</p>
</main>
```

[image: Dev tools]

Comment: Editing CSS stylesheets programmatically is a *really* bad idea for a whole lot of reasons I'm not going to list here. What you're trying to do is not possible using CSS alone, so the current pattern is the most effective solution.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you will want to use the .main selector for jquery as following:

```
$('.main').css('padding-top', headerHeight);
```

Comment: That still sets element.style and not that actual 'main' class.

Comment: @The Interactive DOM another option is create a 2nd class like .mainChanged and then add the class to the element as needed.